# If $E[X|\mathscr{F}] = E[Y|\mathscr{G}]$ then$E[Y|\mathscr{G}] = E[X|\mathscr{F}]$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose we show that $E[X|\mathscr{F}] = E[Y|\mathscr{G}]$, that is that for any $Z$ such that $Z$ is a version of $E[X|\mathscr{F}]$, $Z$ is a version of $E[Y|\mathscr{G}]$. Does it follow that for any version $W$ of $E[Y|\mathscr{G}]$ we have that $W$ is also a version of $E[X|\mathscr{F}]$?

This seems like it really should be true since we are using the $=$ sign to denote "is a version of". But it seems much less obvious when given a specific example.

For instance, suppose $X=Y$ and $\mathscr{G} \subseteq\mathscr{F}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$. Then if $Z$ is a version of both $E[X|\mathscr{G}],E[X|\mathscr{F}]$. Now for $W$ a version of $E[X|\mathscr{F}]$ we know $W=Z$ a.s. [$P$]. But this doesn't imply that $W$ is $\mathscr{F}$-measurable unless $\mathscr{F}$ contains all the $P$-null sets, so $W$ may not qualify to be a version of $E[X|\mathscr{F}]$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you write $E[X|\mathscr{F}] = E[Y|\mathscr{G}]$? Surely this implies that any version is **both** $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a notational problem.

Suppose any version $g$ of $E[X|\mathscr{F}]$ is also a version of $E[Y|\mathscr{G}]$.

This means that $g$ is **both** $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ measurable,  $\int_A g = \int_A X$ for all $A \in \mathscr{F}$, and  $\int_B g = \int_B Y$ for all $B \in \mathscr{G}$.

If $\tilde{g}$ is a version of $E[Y|\mathscr{G}]$, then $g=\tilde{g}$, except on a $\mathscr{G}$ null set. However, there is no a priori reason to presume that a $\mathscr{G}$ null set is a $\mathscr{F}$ null set. That is, $\tilde{g}$ is not necessarily $\mathscr{F}$ measurable.

For example, let $\mathscr{F} = {\cal B} ([0,1])$ (Borel subsets of $[0,1]$) and 
$\mathscr{G} = {\cal M} ([0,1])$ (Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$).
Then any version of $E[1|\mathscr{F}]$ is also a version of $E[1|\mathscr{G}]$.

Now let $N$ be a Lebesgue measurable null set that is **not** Borel (such sets exist because ${\cal B} ([0,1])$ is not complete). Let $\tilde{g} = 1_{ N^c }$. Then $\tilde{g}$ is a version of $E[1|\mathscr{G}]$, but is not $\mathscr{F}$ measurable, hence not a version of $E[1|\mathscr{F}]$.

So, perhaps a better notation would be $E[X|\mathscr{F}] \subset E[Y|\mathscr{G}]$? (Or assume all the relevant sub $\sigma$-algebras are complete.)